# How does this evaluate to true?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am reading PHP Cookbook, in the section about Forms there is this:

Problem: You want to make sure a value has been supplied for a form element. For example, you want to make sure a text box hasn’t been left blank.

Then the author elaborates to this:

```
// Making sure $_POST['flavor'] exists before checking its length
    if (! (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'flavor') &&
        (strlen(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'flavor')) > 0))) {
        print 'You must enter your favorite ice cream flavor.';
    }
```

I don't understand how this 'and' expression evaluates to true.
Won't `!(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'flavor')` always be false?

Comment: `!` operator is applied to the whole `(... && ...)` expression. Which effectively negates it: "if it does not exist or is an empty string"

Comment: if you formate code properly that you wont get these kind of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'flavor')` will make sure form sent `flavor` post variable

`strlen(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'flavor')) > 0` will make sure the `flavor` post variable is other than `""`(empty string)

The `!` operator is applied to the whole expression using `()` and will make sure both these conditions are false for it to be true.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the order of the brackets. Check the carat signs I put under the corresponding brackets:

```
( !(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'flavor') && (strlen(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'flavor'))>0)) )
   ^                                                                                    ^
```

So it actually checks: `"if not both are true"`.

You could rewrite this to `"if X is not true or Y is not true"` like so:

```
( !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'flavor') || !strlen(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'flavor')) > 0 )
```

In my opinion this last version is more readable and therefore I would actually prefer it.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's it. I got tricked by the book identation! And yeah, while trying to understand this I rewrited it with 'or' and it was much more readable indeed.

Comment: @Marconato - If you like the answer you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.. :-)